# Use custom global function in Expression Binding

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I see how to use expression binding.

https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/docs/guide/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0.html

I can use a small range of function call (*You can use functions that are available via global symbols, such as Math.max(...) or isNaN(...).*)

I have my custom function `isVisible(sParam)` but I want write the sParam value directly into the xml code (*sParams is never in the model*), something like this

```
visible='{=isVisible('01 03 05 06')}'
```

My idea is to define isVisible as a **global function** but in debug the program don't cross the function code

```
window.isVisible = function (sParam) {
    ...
};
```

This is the dual Question of [Text string as params in a formatter function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484736/text-string-as-params-in-a-formatter-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only specific global objects and functions allowed. You can see a list in the [sourcecode](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.38/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/ExpressionParser.js#L21) which should be the list of global symbols found in the documentation link you provided.

But I just had an idea:

> Member access operator with the . operator

You can create a 'utility' `JSONModel` that contains functions. A `JSONModel` just takes any javascript object and provides access via binding path and databinding to it. So you access the root object via `/` and call a function on the resulting object:

```
onInit:function(){
  var utility = {
    isEven: function(x){
      return x % 2 === 0;
    }
  };
  this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel(utility), "utility");
}
```

```
<Button text="Hello 1" visible="{:= ${utility>/}.isEven(1) }"/>
<Button text="Hello 2" visible="{:= ${utility>/}.isEven(2) }"/>
```

You can even access the controller via closure.

Of course you can define that utility model at a higher level (at `Component` or even at the `Core`). You can have many utility models and you can mix models in an expression: `visible="{= ${utility>/}.doSomething(${bla>/blub}, 42) }` (not tried that).

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6VXME9Jkepo2TG0LTeJL?p=preview) for an example

Comment: This is a really creative approach! Never though about creating a JSONModel which not only holds JSON data, but JS functions as well

Comment: I'm using 'intelligent models' that use javascript properties `get bla() { ... } set bla(x) { ... }`  for quite some time now. You can bind to these properties like to any attribute. This really helps if you have a lot of dependencies and constraints. You can calculate sums etc. on the fly.